# What does "world outlook" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

> Under these baffling conditions there is no thorough discussion of the
> world outlook whatever, anywhere.

*The new world order by H.G. Wells*

I interpret the "world" outlook as "world state". Am I right?
Or what does the author mean by it?

My other question is, what does "whatever" mean here?

Comment: I think that this is on topic, if you are using *The New World Order* to learn English.  But also be aware of [literature.se] which focuses more on "What the author means".  We are not best for interpreting works of literarture.

Comment: I understand. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "outlook" is what the state of something is in the future.

You might, for example, ask about the weather outlook for the next five days.

So, by analogy, the world outlook would be "the state of the world in the future (ie from the time when the book was written in 1940 forwards)"

<sub>whatever, or [whatsoever](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/whatsoever), are used after a negative phrase to add emphasis to the idea that is being expressed</sub>